# Does severe multicollinearity affect solving linear regression by gradient descent?

Tags: machine-learning, statistics, linear-regression, optimization, gradient-descent

Since OLS may fail when there is severe/near perfect multicollinearity, how would gradient descent perform in such a scenario? 
Does it converge at the minima?

(My guess is, Cost function of linear regression is always convex. so nothing should stop steepest descent algorithms from coverging)

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that the cost function of [linear regression](https://databasecamp.de/en/ml/linear-regression-basics) is convex, meaning it has a single global minimum. In theory, this property ensures that [gradient descent](https://databasecamp.de/en/ml/gradient-descent) algorithms, such as ordinary least squares, should converge to the global minimum, even in the presence of [multicollinearity](https://databasecamp.de/en/statistics/multicollinearity). However, [multicollinearity](https://databasecamp.de/en/statistics/multicollinearity) can still pose challenges for [gradient descent](https://databasecamp.de/en/ml/gradient-descent):

1. **Slower Convergence:** [Multicollinearity](https://databasecamp.de/en/statistics/multicollinearity) leads to high condition numbers in the design matrix, making the cost function very steep. [Gradient descent](https://databasecamp.de/en/ml/gradient-descent) can become slow in these cases because it takes smaller steps to converge. The algorithm may require more iterations to reach the minimum.
2. **Numerical Stability:** Severe [multicollinearity](https://databasecamp.de/en/statistics/multicollinearity) can make the problem numerically unstable. The gradients may become extremely large, causing numerical instability and making it difficult for the algorithm to converge.
3. **Ill-Conditioned Matrices:** When [multicollinearity](https://databasecamp.de/en/statistics/multicollinearity) is severe, the design matrix can be close to singular, causing issues in matrix inversion or solving linear systems of equations during [gradient descent](https://databasecamp.de/en/ml/gradient-descent) updates. This may lead to convergence problems.

To address these challenges when using [gradient descent](https://databasecamp.de/en/ml/gradient-descent) in the presence of [multicollinearity](https://databasecamp.de/en/statistics/multicollinearity), you can consider the following approaches:

1. **Feature Selection or Dimension Reduction:** If you suspect severe [multicollinearity](https://databasecamp.de/en/statistics/multicollinearity), consider feature selection techniques or dimension reduction methods (e.g., [principal component analysis](https://databasecamp.de/en/statistics/principal-component-analysis-en)) to reduce the number of highly correlated features.
2. **Regularization:** Regularization techniques, such as Ridge (L2) or Lasso (L1) regression, can help mitigate [multicollinearity](https://databasecamp.de/en/statistics/multicollinearity) by adding penalty terms to the cost function. These methods encourage coefficient values to be small and can stabilize [gradient descent](https://databasecamp.de/en/ml/gradient-descent).
3. **Data Preprocessing:** Standardize or normalize your input features to ensure they are on a similar scale. This can help gradient descent algorithms converge more quickly and accurately.
4. **Advanced Optimization Algorithms:** Consider using more advanced optimization algorithms like L-BFGS, which can handle ill-conditioned problems more effectively and converge faster than vanilla gradient descent.

In summary, while the convexity of the [linear regression](https://databasecamp.de/en/ml/linear-regression-basics) cost function theoretically ensures convergence in the presence of [multicollinearity](https://databasecamp.de/en/statistics/multicollinearity), the practical challenges associated with steep cost surfaces, numerical stability, and ill-conditioned matrices can slow down or complicate gradient descent.